# Avoid that when refreshing the page, the global status is lost with Vuex and VueRouter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I'm creating a SPA, and as a basic example of sessions on the client side, I'm using Vuex to store a boolean state if the user is logged in or not, it works fine while not manually updating the browser. As the state restarts to its initial state, is there any way to prevent this or should it always use localstorage? If so, how to get the initial state of storage?

**Component Navbar**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul v-if="!isLogued">
            <router-link :to="{ name:'login'}" class="nav-link">Login</router-link>
        </ul>
        <ul  v-if="isLogued">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Profile</a>
                <a href="" @click.prevent="logout">Salir</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import {mapState,mapMutations  } from 'vuex';
    export default{
        computed : mapState(['isLogued']),
        methods:{
            ...mapMutations(['logout']),
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Store.js**

```
export default {
    state: {
        userLogued: {},
        api_token  : '',
        isLogued : false
    },
    mutations: {

        login( state){
            state.userLogued = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuario'));
            state.api_token = localStorage.getItem('api_token');
            state.isLogued =  true
        },

        logout(state){
            state.userLogued = {}
            state.isLogued = false
            state.api_token  = null
            localStorage.clear()
        }
    }
};
```

**App.JS**

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(Vuex)

import store from './vuex/store';
import routes from './routes';
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})

const app = new Vue({
   router,
   store : new Vuex.Store(store)
}).$mount('#app')
```

In my login component, I do post with axios and if it is correct I do the following

```
   methods : {
        ...mapMutations(['login']),
        sendLogin(){
            axios.post('/api/login' , this.form)
                .then(res =>{
                    localStorage.setItem('api_token', res.data.api_token);
                    localStorage.setItem('user_logued', JSON.stringify(res.data.usuario));
                    this.login();
                    this.$router.push('/');
                })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to always be using a persistent storage mechanism if you want to preserve state across page reloads, browser sessions, etc. You can use localStorage, sessionStorage, cookies, indexeddb... whichever best suits your needs, although sessionStorage is of course only good for the current session.

To restore the initial state, use a plugin for Vuex, such as [vuex-peristedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate). This will take case of the saving/restoring vuex to storage for you.

For example, creating an instance of `vuex-persistedstate` for use in your store is as easy as:

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // ...
  plugins: [createPersistedState()]
})
```